# How to filter objects that were created today (Django)

Tags: django, datetime

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(date__range=[datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.timedelta(days=1)])
```

I guess this doesn't do exactly what i want, but when i type this into my python shell i keep getting this warning.

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2012-08-26 02:03:25.614372) while time zone support is active.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's datetime objects now support time zones. `datetime.datetime.now()` returns naive objects (w/o timezone). To compare them you need to make `datetime.datetime.now()` timezone-aware.

You can use `django.utils.timezone`, which has an API for making `datetime.datetime` instances timezone-aware.

For example:

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.make_aware(datetime_object, tzinfo_object)
```

Refer to [Django Time Zones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: [import datetime]
[from django.utils.timezone import utc]

[now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)]

it tell me to do this, but how can i make the timezone be PST?

Comment: If you have `pytz` installed, you can get it using `import pytz tz=pytz.timezone('US/PST')`

Answer (score 9):

This may help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range). 
I didn`t check this code, but:

```
import datetime
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
orders = Order.objects.filter(date__gt=yesterday)
```

It will bring all Orders, which date field contains date over yesterday. Since you have no Orders from future, this may work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with timezone aware dates, I recommend getting the first instant of the day and filter with that.

```
dt = timezone.now()
start = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
Order.objects.filter(created__gte=start)
```

Note that if you want orders from another day like for instance yesterday, that's quite easy:

```
dt = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)
start = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
end = dt.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)
Order.objects.filter(created__range=(start, end))
```

Source [here](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/date-lookups-django/)