# Django: DateTime query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model

```
class Booked(models.Model):
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resouce)
```

How do I check if a particular datetime range doesn't fall between the start or end datetimes of any of the booked objects?

I want to check if I can book a resource with say `book_start_date` and `book_end_date` without it being already booked during that range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`__lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lte) and [`__gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte) with [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) to check if there is something in the date range:

```
Booked.objects.exists(start_date_time__lte=book_end_date, 
                      end_date_time__gte=book_start_date)
```

See also: [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap).

Comment: You can use __range either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range