# Oracle date query in django

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-1.7

This is the SQL I get from Django when making a date query on Oracle (i is an instance of `Model.objects`):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dates = [dt(2014,07,01), dt(2014,07,02)]
print i.filter(incd_date_d__range=dates).query

SELECT "SCHEMA"."TABLE"."COL1", "SCHEMA"."TABLE"."DATE_COL" 
FROM "SCHEMA"."TABLE" 
WHERE "SCHEMA"."TABLE"."DATE_COL" 
BETWEEN 2014-07-01 00:00:00 AND 2014-07-02 00:00:00
```

This returns a database error (`ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23`). Notice how the dates are **not** surrounded by inverted commas. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range Does this work for you?

Comment: What type is `incd_date_d`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `DateTimeField()`.

Comment: What's your database driver?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid oracle-instantclient12.1-odbc-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm & unixODBC-2.2.14

Comment: Its strange because I did the exact query and I don't get any errors, which makes me suspect the driver. For reference, you should not use the ODBC driver use the following: `oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` and `oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` from the Oracle [download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You may be right. However, SQLAlchemy works seamlessly with the current setup, and so does cx_Oracle.

Comment: I ran this query, with the same output as yours, and it did not give me an error from Oracle; so I don't think this has to do with inverted commas.

Comment: Interesting, because it gives me an error when I run this query in Oracle SQL Developer running in a remote desktop.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I actually have the drivers you suggested installed.