# Django: filter datetime in date on date range

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter the query set on between two dates.
here is my views.py

```
week = (startDate, endDate)
Student.objects.filter(created__range=week)
```

- startDate and endDate is date objects
- created is my datetime field

but I want filter on only date

i'd like to match the month, day, year exactly, not the time.

expected output is filter queryset between startDate and endDate

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range

Comment: @warath-coder Nope. Objects in the range are dates but search field is the datetime.  So simple `__range` will cut all data at `endDate` (`2015-02-10` is less than `2015-02-10 00:00:01`)

Comment: if you go to that link, all the possible solutions are there, so yes this is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the `__range` lookup with `__gte`/`__lt` combination.

```
Student.objects.filter(created__gte=startDate,
                       created__lt=endDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```