# Django model time stamp range filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model field `time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now)`. Now I want to search based on date range, like 2016-11-08 to 2016-12-08. How can I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django database query: How to filter objects by date range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)

Comment: date_range can be easily used in DateField but this is DateTimeField

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup:

> Filtering a `DateTimeField` with dates won’t include items on the last day, because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given date”.

Considering this, If you want items from the last date i.e. `2016-12-08`, you could consider using `2016-12-09` in the filtering.

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2016, 11, 8)
# use the day after 2016-12-08 to include it
end_date = datetime.date(2016, 12, 9)
Model.objects.filter(time_stamp__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

---

Or, use `gte` and `lte` lookups:

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2016, 11, 8)
end_date = datetime.date(2016, 12, 8)
Model.objects.filter(time_stamp__gte=start_date, time_stamp__lte=end_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.objects.filter(time_stamp__range=["2016-11-08", "2016-12-08"])
```

Links [Django database query: How to filter objects by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)

Answer (score 0):

If your django version is >= 1.9 you can use the `date` casting on datetime field.

```
Model.objects.filter(time_stamp__date__gte=start_date, time_stamp__date__lte=end_date)
```

This will consider the timezone conversions also. Problem with other answers is that they are not considering that the filtering is being done on a `datetime` field.

Django documentation on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date