# How can I check whether an entry that a user inputs has already been entered by him/her in the past 30 days in my django website

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am building a survey website using Django 1.7.7 and Python 3.4.4, where a user enters say his "name" and "id". I have a sql table called "list" that stores all the users names and id's. I would like my Django website to check if when a user enters his/her name and id, if the id already exists in the table for the past 30 days. Basically if the user's id exists in the past 30 days, he/she will not be prompted to take the survey, else they would have to take the survey.

I know I have to build a view function that checks this condition but I am unable to figure out what the query/logic should be. Any help on the view function would help me out in my development immensely! Thank you.

Comment: seems like you need to add a timestamp to your database that you update as needed.  Then you can check the timestamp as needed .

Comment: In the "list" table, do you have a column that records the date of a submission? Your database does not automatically record that data, you have to add a datetime column and update your submission process accordingly. After that, you can just use Django's ORM to query & filter by time. Check this solution for an example of querying by date range: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6194999/844976

Answer (score 1):

You can add "timestamp" field to your List model. You can even make Django automatically set it to `now()` using `auto_now_add` parameter

```
 timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Than you can check if there are records with the same name and id within last month:

```
 from django.utils.timezone import now
 import datetime
 is_duplicate = List.objects.filter(id=id, name=name, timestamp__gte = now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30))
```

Note usages of __gte construtions - it means "greater than", and can be used with numbers and timestamps. This filter will only return records created within past 30 days. Hope this helps!