# Filter query with range within Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to execute a query with the [range test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range) in my class (MapArea), but I don't seem to have a grasp on the visibility of objects in Models as I get `NameError: name 'MapArea' is not defined`.

My class is as follows:

```
class MapArea(models.Model):

    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    nearby_streets = MapArea.objects.filter(lat__range=[self.lat - 2, self.lat + 2], lon__range=[self.lon - 2, self.lon + 2])

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Setting `nearby_streets` to `MapArea.objects.filter(lat__range=[self.lat - 2, self.lat + 2], lon__range=[self.lon - 2,  self.lon + 2])` is what causes the `NameError: name 'MapArea' is not defined`.

It seems like MapArea should be defined [according to other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668718/2716435), but I don't seem to be accessing it correctly. How can I access `MapArea.objects.filter()` in order to use the range test feature?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a model field with such a behaviour. All the model fields are stored in the database, but `nearby_streets` seems to be something you query, so it's better as a method or property.

You could do something like this

```
class MapArea(models.Model):

    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=6)

    # Meta
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @property
    nearby_streets = MapArea.objects.filter(lat__range=[self.lat - 2, self.lat + 2], lon__range=[self.lon - 2, self.lon + 2])
```

And in the rest of your code you can access it from any instance of MapArea as such `map_area.nearby_streets`

Keep in mind that properties, just like methods are computed every time they are called, so if you call nearby_streets twice, it will hit the database twice...

You could use [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) instead of property, so that the database is hit only once.