# custom filter on contact by date - django rest framework

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a table in which I display information about organizations and I have a mechanism who is triggering next action date on the organization, that is manually set on the organizations.
Now I've added a custom `datepicker` field on top of my table so I can filter it for the wanted date and show all `next action date` for that organization on selected date, so I'm passing a value to `Controller` so I can catch in the `restAPI`, and in the `rest` I want to **filter the date to be before or equal to now** so I can show organizations by next action date.
My question is how to **filter the date to be before or equal to now**, I really lost here so can someone help me and explain how can I do that in my `ModelViewSet`.

ModelViewSet:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, filters

from cms.restapi.pagination import StandardResultsOffsetPagination
from cms_sales.models import LeadContact
from cms_sales.restapi.permissions.lead_contact_permissions import LeadContactPermissions
from cms_sales.restapi.serializers.lead_contact_serializer import LeadContactSerializer


class LeadContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = LeadContact.objects.none()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.has_perm('vinclucms_sales.can_view_full_lead_contact_list'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.all()
        elif user.has_perm('vinclucms_sales.can_view_lead_contact'):
            queryset = LeadContact.objects.filter(account_handler=user)
        return queryset

    serializer_class = LeadContactSerializer

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter)

    filter_fields = ('account_handler',)

    ordering_fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_handler__first_name', 'account_handler__last_name',
        'sub_organization_name', 'organization_name', 'next_action_date', 'serial_number',
        'next_action_date', 'status_text', 'select_date')

    search_fields = (
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_handler__first_name', 'account_handler__last_name',
        'sub_organization_name', 'organization_name', 'next_action_date', 'serial_number',
        'next_action_date', 'status_text', 'select_date')

    pagination_class = StandardResultsOffsetPagination

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, LeadContactPermissions]
```

Cotroller where I pass the `datepicker` field:

```
app = angular.module 'cms.sales'

app.controller 'LeadContactListCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$compile', 'LeadContacts'
  ($scope, $rootScope, $compile, LeadContacts) ->
    savedSuccessMessage = "Lead Contact List was updated"
    savedFailMessage = "Failed to update lead contact list"

    $scope.init = ()->
      fetchLeadContacts()

    fetchLeadContacts = () ->
      $('#expensesListTable').DataTable(
        createdRow: (row, data, index) ->
          $compile(row)($scope)
        sDom: 'lfrtip'
        processing: true
        serverSide: true
        searchDelay: 1000
        orderMulti: false
        pageLength: 25
        ajax:
          url: '/api/sales/lead_contact/'
          data: (data) ->
            data.limit = data.length
            data.offset = data.start
            data.search = data.search['value']
            if data.order[0]['dir'] == 'asc'
              data.ordering = data.columns[data.order[0]['column']].name
            else
              data.ordering = '-' + data.columns[data.order[0]['column']].name
            return 0
          dataFilter: (data) ->
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
            json.recordsTotal = json.count
            json.recordsFiltered = json.count
            json.data = json.results
            return JSON.stringify json
        columns: [
          {
            data: 'serial_number'
            name: 'serial_number'
            render: (data, type, row, meta) ->
              return '<a href="{{ site.domain }}' + row.absolute_url + '">' + data + '</a>'
          }
          {
            name: 'first_name,last_name'
            render: (data, type, row, meta)->
              return row['first_name'] + ' ' + row['last_name']
          }
          {
            data: 'organization_name'
            name: 'organization_name'
          }
          {
            data: 'sub_organization_name'
            name: 'sub_organization_name'
          }
          {
            data: 'account_handler'
            name: 'account_handler__first_name, account_handler__last_name'
            render: (data, type, row, meta)->
              return data['first_name'] + ' ' + data['last_name']
          }
          {
            data: 'status_text'
            name: 'status_text'
            render: (data, type, row, meta)->
              return "<span class='" + row['status_display_class'] + "'>" + data + "</span>"
          }
          {
            data: "next_action_date"
            name: "next_action_date"
            render: (data, type, row, meta)->
              initValue = data
              if data
                initValue = "'" + data + "'"
              return '<div class="input-control text" data-role="datepicker"
                         ng-controller="ContactDateCtrl"
                         ng-init="init(' + row['pk'] + ', ' + initValue + ')"
                         data-format="mmmm d, yyyy">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="contactDate" ng-change="onChange()">
                        <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                    </div>'
          }
        ])

    $scope.SelectLeadContacts = () ->
      params = {}
      if $scope.lead_contact.id
        params['id'] = $scope.lead_contact.id
        LeadContacts.update(params).$promise.then saveSuccessCallback, saveFailedCallback
      else
        LeadContacts.save(params).$promise.then saveSuccessCallback, saveFailedCallback

    saveSuccessCallback = (response) ->
      ClientNotifications.showNotification("Success", savedSuccessMessage, "success")

    saveFailedCallback = (error) ->
      ClientNotifications.showNotification("Alert", savedFailMessage, "alert")

    $scope.showAddNew = ()->
      initNewLeadContacts()

    initNewLeadContacts = ()->
      $scope.lead_contact = {}
      $scope.lead_contact.select_date = 'Jan 1, 2200'

]
```

Template:

```
{% extends "site_base.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block head_title %}Lead contact list{% endblock %}

{% block ng_app %}cms.sales{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="align-center">
                <strong>
                    {% trans "Contact leads List" %}
                </strong>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grid"
         ng-controller="LeadContactListCtrl"
         ng-init="init()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell size-p20 padding10">
                <label for="id_select_date">Select Date: *</label>
                <div class="full-size">
                    <div class="input-control full-size text"
                    data-role="datepicker" date-format="mmmm d, yyyy">
                        <input id="id_select_date" ng-model="lead_contact.select_date"/>
                        <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell size-p20 padding10">
                <button class="button primary" ng-click="SelectLeadContacts()">
                    {% trans "Submit" %}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell size-p100 padding10">
                <table title="Contact leads List" class="dataTable" id="contactLeadsList">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{% trans 'Serial Number' %}</th>
                        <th>{% trans 'Lead name' %}</th>
                        <th>{% trans 'Organization' %}</th>
                        <th>{% trans 'Sub-organization' %}</th>
                        <th>{% trans 'Handler' %}</th>
                        <th>{% trans 'Sale status' %}</th>
                        <th>{% trans 'Next communication date' %}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've fully understood what you're asking, but to filter a QuerySet to only display objects with a `next_action_date` in the future you can use:

```
import datetime
LeadContact.objects.filter(next_action_date__gte=datetime.date.today())
```

and to display only those with dates in the past use:

```
LeadContact.objects.filter(next_action_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range) for a more detailed guide on filtering QuerySets by date. In particular, if the type of your `next_action_date` field is datetime, use `datetime.datetime.now()` rather than `datetime.date.today()`. More info also in the [QuerySet docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#dates).

Comment: Ok, thanks, as for now, I've figure out that `lte` and `gte` will help me do this, nevertheless I will accept your answer because It is helpful