# Filter with 'date' in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

In model.py, I create class Order has a field 'order_date' with DateTimeField.

In views.py, I am using this query:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(order_date__date__gte = date_from, order_date__date__lte = date_to)
```

The Query doesn't return any data, although in the database, there are many records between date_from and date_to.

Comment: can you post the date_from and date_to codes, how are you taking it

Comment: you have typo in `order_day__date__gte` it should be `order_date__date__gte`

Comment: @Satendra, I fixed, change `order_day` into `order_date` but I still receive my result I want.

Comment: use `date_from.date()` and  `date_to.date()` inspite of `date_from` and `date_to` in query, let me know if this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django database query: How to filter objects by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)

Comment: @Satendra, I use the query: 
`orders = Order.objects.filter(order_date__date__gte = date_from.date(), order_date__date__lte = date_to.date())` 
I have an error: **'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'**, although I add `from datetime import date`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(order_date__gte = date_from, order_date__lte = date_to)
```

You have an extra __date that you don't need, since order_date is a DateTimeField.

Comment: If I don't use `__date`, when I set `date_from` is '11/30/2017', in the query `date_from` will set 11/30/2017 00:00:00'. And `date_to` is the same.

Comment: are date_from and date_to strings or date objects?

Comment: I use `if date_from_str and date_to_str:
        date_from = getDateFromString(date_from_str)
        date_to = getDateFromString(date_to_str)
    else:
        date_from = datetime.date.today()
        date_to = datetime.date.today()` 
to get date.