# How to calculate number of remaining monthly recurring dates between now and a date in the future in Django with Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application with Django Rest Framework that is storing records in Postgres.
A `Vehicle` model has an `end_date` `DateField` that represents the final payment date of a finance agreement, and a `monthly_payment` `FloatField` that represents the payment amount. The finance payment is made monthly, on the same day of the month as the final payment (e.g. if `end_date` is 25/01/2020, a payment is made on the 25th of every month between now and 25/01/2020 inclusive.)

I have a `ListVehicle` `ListCreateAPIView` that returns a paginated list of vehicle records.
I am using a custom `PageNumberPagination` class to return a `data` object alongside the `results` array that is populated by aggregating some of the fields in the `Vehicle` model.
I want to include a field in this `data` object that contains the total remaining amount left to pay on all of the `Vehicle` entities in the database.

I have tried using `@property` fields in the model that calculate the total remaining amount for each `Vehicle`, but you [can't aggregate over calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341867/django-property-used-in-aggregate) (at least not with `queryset.aggregate`), so the following solution did not work:

```py
    @property
    def remaining_balance(self):
        return max(self.remaining_monthly_payments * self.monthly_payment, 0)

    @property
    def remaining_monthly_payments(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        end = self.end_date

        months = (end.year - now.year) * 12
        months -= now.month + 1
        months += end.month

        today = now.day
        final_day = end.day

        if today < final_day:
            months += 1

        return months
```

I have also tried using `ExpressionWrapper`s in the pagination class to first annotate each `Vehicle` with a `time_remaining` field and then annotated to have a `remaining_balance` field calculated by extracting the month from `time_remaining` and multiplying it by `monthly_payment`. Then `remaining_balance` is aggregated.

```py
class VehicleFinancePagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        duration = ExpressionWrapper(F('end_date') - Now(), output_field=fields.DurationField())
        queryset = queryset.annotate(duration=duration)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(remaining_balance=ExpressionWrapper(ExtractMonth('duration') * F('monthly_payment'), output_field=FloatField()))

        self.total_remaining_balance = queryset.aggregate(total_remaining_balance=Sum('remaining_balance'))[
            "total_remaining_balance"]
        return super(VehicleFinancePagination, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        paginated_response = super(VehicleFinancePagination, self).get_paginated_response(data)
        paginated_response.data['total_remaining_balance'] = self.total_remaining_balance

        return paginated_response
```

I have tried several combinations of annotations in this style. (including doing the entire calculation in one annotation). This returns 0 every time. I get a value if I use `ExtractDay` instead of `ExtractMonth`, so I think the problem here is that `ExtractMonth` gets the month of a year from a `DateField`, but not the number of full months in a `DurationField` like I'd hoped, although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856951/its-possible-to-get-months-between-two-dates-in-django-queryset) would suggest otherwise

Another thing that doesn't work is storing the remaining balance/remaining months with the `Vehicle` when it is saved. As soon as a monthly payment date passes, a `Vehicle` will be out of date until the next time it is saved and as such the aggregated totals will be incorrect.

Have I got the wrong approach? Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with a custom database query, and if so would it be the best way?

Using PostgreSQL 10.10, Django 2.2, DRF 3.9.4 and Python 3.6

EDIT:
Testcase for completeness

```py
    @mock.patch('workshop.models.vehicle.datetime')
    def test_remaining_balance(self, mocked_datetime):
        mocked_datetime.datetime.now.return_value = datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3)

        Vehicle.objects.create(registration="TS01 TST", monthly_payment=500, end_date=datetime.date(2020, 3, 1)) #2000
        Vehicle.objects.create(registration="TS02 TST", monthly_payment=250, end_date=datetime.date(2020, 3, 25)) #1250
        Vehicle.objects.create(registration="TS03 TST", monthly_payment=400, end_date=datetime.date(2020, 5, 1)) #2400
        Vehicle.objects.create(registration="TS04 TST", monthly_payment=300, end_date=datetime.date(2020, 5, 25)) #2100
        Vehicle.objects.create(registration="TS03 TST", monthly_payment=400, end_date=datetime.date(2018, 5, 1)) #0
        Vehicle.objects.create(registration="TS04 TST", monthly_payment=300, end_date=datetime.date(2018, 5, 25)) #0

        url = reverse('vehicles')
        response = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['total_remaining_balance'],  7750)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should give you the annotation that you want

The PostgreSQL [age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-datetime.html) function will give you an interval from which we can get the number of months. We can define a custom DB function:

```
class Age(Func):
    function = 'AGE'
```

Then we can chain some annotations to calculate the number of months. The interval will be something like `1 year 2 mon 3 days 00:00:00` and `ExtractMonth` will return `2` for this example so we also need to extract the year and multiply it by 12:

```
queryset.annotate(
    diff=Age(F('end_date'), datetime.date.today())
).annotate(
    months=ExtractYear('diff') * 12 + ExtractMonth('diff')
)
```

Then we can chain a further annotation where we calculate the remaining balance using the previous annotations. We have to use `ExpressionWrapper` and cast to a float as `months` and `monthly_payment` are different types:

```
queryset.annotate(
    diff=Age(F('end_date'), datetime.date.today())
).annotate(
    months=ExtractYear('diff') * 12 + ExtractMonth('diff')
).annotate(
    remaining_balance=ExpressionWrapper(F('months') * F('monthly_payment'), output_field=models.FloatField())
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. If I were to switch to a different database, would I need to reimplement it? (or would django handle using an equivalent database function in say MySQL with this code?)

Comment: You need to change the months annotation to:

`months=Greatest(ExtractYear('diff') * 12 + ExtractMonth('diff') + 1, 0)`