# How to filter records by range of date in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can I filter records by range of date given by the user?

I want to create a Daterange form(it will contain start date and end date) in django where the user will give their specific dates and it will filter the objects based on that dates given by the user...

Can I perform this in Django?

Comment: Yes, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668718/1189656) to see how to filter by date range.

Comment: `MyModel.objects.filter(Q(datetime__lte=request.POST['end_date']) & Q(datetime__gte=request.POST['start_date'])` Assuming `datetimefield` of your model is called datetime.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal what's wrong with `range` lookups ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, say the model looks like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

You can get all `MyModel` objects between `2018-1-1` and `2018-2-9` with:

```
from datetime import date

MyModel.objects.filter(date__range=(date(2018,1,1), date(2018, 2, 9)))
```

You can thus use a form like:

```
class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField()
    end_date = forms.DateField()
```

and then filter in the view like:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DateRangeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            qs = MyModel.objects.filter(date__range=(
                form.cleaned_data['start_date'],
                form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            ))
            # do something
         else:
            # do something
            pass
    else:
        # do something
        pass
```

Comment: Yeah that will do...Thanx@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: Can you plz tell me how to do this same thing under class based detail view??

Comment: @NiladryKar: the main idea is that in the queryset, you use `my_date_field__range=(from_date, to_date)`, but filtering in a detail-view is already quite strange in itself.

Comment: OOOO yes...I have done it in function based views...Thanx for your help again@Willem Van Onsem