# DJANGO How to make a Q query that can filter between two values?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am making a real estate application in which I am stuck right now on a search functionality . My main problem is that I have to make a search function that can filter a query set based on the choices user chooses.
And i am able to do it but the problem is there are two options that user can filter on and that's area and price and they both have min and max value so how I have to make a filter that can take both min and max values and then present the filter queryset which contains the objects that have values between the min and max.

Here's my search function

```
    def search(request):
        queryset = models.Property.objects.all()
        query1 = request.GET.get('q1')
        query2 = request.GET.get('q2')
        query3 = request.GET.get('q3')
        query4 = request.GET.get('q4')
        query5 = request.GET.get('q5')
        query6 = request.GET.get('q6')

        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(status__icontains=query)|
                Q(address__icontains=query2)|
                Q(rooms__icontains=query3)| 
                Q(bathroom__icontains=query4)|
                Q(area__icontains=query5)|
                Q(price__icontains=query6)
                ).all()

            return render(request,'properties/properties_search_list.html',{'queryset':queryset})
```

Here's the area and price code in html

```
                    <div class="range-slider">
                            <label>Area</label>
                            <div data-min="0" data-max="10000" data-min-name="min_area" data-max-name="max_area" data-unit="Sq ft" class="range-slider-ui ui-slider" aria-disabled="false" name="q5" ></div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-slider">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <div data-min="0" data-max="150000"  data-min-name="min_price" data-max-name="max_price" data-unit="USD" class="range-slider-ui ui-slider" aria-disabled="false" name="q6" ></div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I filter query objects by date range in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/how-do-i-filter-query-objects-by-date-range-in-django)

Comment: But how will I grab the units of max and min from html.

Comment: To make this question Django-related: make hidden inputs, copy values into them from data-attrs of demonstrated divs by JS handlers. So it will become a regular form. Also you'll be able to show these inputs in no-js mode, for instance.

Comment: I don't know how to do it.Can you please write the answer

Comment: So get rid of magic sliders for now and accomplish this with simple `input` fields.

Comment: No sir The client wants these kinds of sliders.