# Django range data with from and to date

Tags: django

I try create to queryset with dates - from=2019.01.01 to 2019.01.02 . And i want output all data who fell into this range with 2019.01.01 and 2019.01.02 inclusive

My models:

```
class Commitment(models.Model):
scheduled_date = models.DateField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                            blank=True)
```

Not work:

```
    commitments = Commitment.objects.filter(dealer=dealer,
                                            scheduled_date__year=get_next_year(),
                                            created__date__gte=self.from_date,
                                            created__date__lte=self.to_data)
```

Not work:

```
    commitment_query = Q(dealer=dealer)
    commitment_query.add(Q(scheduled_date__year=get_next_year()), Q.AND)
    commitment_query.add(Q(created_date__gte=self.from_date), Q.AND)
    commitment_query.add(Q(created_date__lte=self.to_data), Q.AND)
    commitments1 = Commitment.objects.filter(commitment_query)
```

Not work:

```
commitments = Commitment.objects.filter(dealer=dealer,
                                                    scheduled_date__year=get_next_year(),
                                                    created_date__range=(self.from_date, self.to_data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already on the right path

it should be

```
Q(visit_date__gte=self.from_date) & Q(visit_date__lte=self.to_data)
```

Like so

```
commitments = Commitment.objects.filter(dealer=dealer,
                                            scheduled_date__year=get_next_year(),
                                            Q(visit_date__gte=self.from_date) & Q(visit_date__lte=self.to_data))
```

PS. there's a typo in your `*self.to_data`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding brackets instead of parentheses to your range filter

```
commitments = Commitment.objects.filter(dealer=dealer)\
                                .filter(created_date__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

edit:

[How do I filter query objects by date range in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/how-do-i-filter-query-objects-by-date-range-in-django)

Check the accepted answer for formatting date correctly.

Comment: Can you show how your from and to dates are formatted?