# DateTime filter in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an api which returns weather data of particular city for n number of days given.(api definition: weatherdata/city_name/ndays/).I have problem sorting out data for ndays.

I sorted out the city name using simple icontains. similarly I want to sort out for ndays. previous ndays data needs to be shown. example: suppose today is 2019-08-29, on providing ndays to be 6, weather data of particular city has to be provided from 2019-08-24 to 2019-08-26.

```py
views.py


class weatherDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, city_name, ndays):
        try:
            x = weatherdata.objects.filter(city_name__icontains=city_name)
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            fromdate =  now - timedelta(days=ndays)
            y = 

            return x
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        city_name = kwargs['city_name']
        snippet = self.get_object(city_name,ndays)
        serializer = weatherdataserializer(snippet,many =True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```py
models.py

class weatherdata(models.Model):
    city_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    city_id     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latitude    = models.FloatField(null=True , blank=True)
    longitude   = models.FloatField(null=True , blank=True)
    dt_txt      = models.DateTimeField()
    temp        = models.FloatField(null = False)
    temp_min    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    temp_max    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    pressure    = models.FloatField(null = False) 
    sea_level   = models.FloatField(null = False)
    grnd_level  = models.FloatField(null = False)
    humidity    = models.FloatField(null = False)
    main        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clouds      = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    wind_speed  = models.FloatField(null = False)
    wind_degree = models.FloatField(null = False)
```

```py
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('weatherdata/', views.weatherList.as_view()),
    path('weatherdata/<str:city_name>/<int:ndays>/', views.weatherDetail.as_view()),
]
```

I want 'y' to be filtering objects based on dates. previous ndays data has to be returned. get_object should return the objects which falls under both x and y what needs to be modified in my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/how-do-i-filter-query-objects-by-date-range-in-django

Comment: @GiannisKatsini does using ..filter(dt_txt__range =["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"]) sorts the date?

Comment: It returns the objects in that date range, if you want to sort them, use `order_by='dt_txt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your query like below

```
class weatherDetail(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self, city_name, ndays):
        x = weatherdata.objects.filter(city_name__icontains=city_name)
        today_date = timezone.now().date()
        fromdate =  today_date - timedelta(days=ndays)
        x = x.filter(dt_txt__gte=fromdate).order_by('dt_txt')
        return x

    def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        city_name = kwargs['city_name']
        snippet = self.get_queryset(city_name, ndays)
        serializer = weatherdataserializer(snippet, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```