# Django : filter object based on a date

Tags: python, django, date, object, filter

I'm trying to filter my request based on a date field.

I would like to check if a date is greater than the current date.

This is what I tried, based on this answer : [How do I filter query objects by date range in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/how-do-i-filter-query-objects-by-date-range-in-django/4668703#4668703)

```
orders.object.filter(deliveryDay__gt = date.today()).order_by('-id')
```

Once I get the orders that are not yet delivered, I want to return them to my API to be able to process them in the front-end

Unfortunately it didn't work in my query which returns all orders to me regardless of the date.

I don't understand where is my error.

This is my model :

```
class order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(memberArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    orderDay = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deliveryDay = models.DateField()
    deliveryAddress = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,
                             blank=True, default="Waiting")
    price = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    response = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add more details of how you use this ( maybe whole view and your model field)

Comment: I edited my post and added the model I was using

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
orders.object.filter(deliveryDay__gt = datetime.now()).order_by('-id')
```