# Querying users based on time

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add a class-based view to return users created from one date to another date. I have tried the following are there other ways to filter the user-created between two dates?
While doing this I get:

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to_date'
```

views.py

```
class RegisteredUserFilter(APIView):
    serializer = RegisteredUserFilterSerializer

    def get(self, from_date, to_date):
        userondate = User.objects.filter(created_at__range=[from_date, to_date]).values()
        return Response({"User": userondate})
```

serializers.py

```
class RegisteredUserFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    from_date = serializers.DateField()
    to_date = serializers.DateField()
    model = User
```

full code at: https://github.com/abinashkarki/rest_framework_authentication/tree/master/authapp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I filter query objects by date range in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/how-do-i-filter-query-objects-by-date-range-in-django)

Comment: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html this the solution

Answer (score 1):

## using Django filters

### serilaizers.py

add the following

```
class RegisteredUserFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'created_at']
```

### make file name it filters.py in same path of views.py

### filters.py

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet
import django_filters
from .models import User
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget


class UserFilter(FilterSet):
    date_range = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(label='Date Range', field_name='created_at',
                                                      widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['created_at']
```

### Views.py

```
from .serializers import RegisteredUserFilterSerializer
from .filters import UserFilter
from  django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class RegisteredUserFilter(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisteredUserFilterSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = UserFilter
    model = User
```

### urls.py  add

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RegisteredUserFilter
urlpatterns = [
    path('users-filter/', RegisteredUserFilter.as_view(), name="user-filter"),


]
```

finally do not forget to make

> > pip install django-filter
> > and add it to installed app in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_filters',
]
```

for more information refer to https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html

## another approach

you can make this process manually by overriding the get method and getting query parameters manually
and return response after serializing the query set